# How to find out centos7 ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, amazon-ami

Could anyone give explanation to how to find out centos linux7 instances in AWS console. I have few centos instances in console. AS per recent AWS email centos linux7 need migration. I want to migrate affected instances.

1. How to find out ec2 instances belong to centos linux 7 category. (i will not able to ssh EC2 instance to use cat /etc/os-release)i need to find out from console only. how?
2. few said with AMI we can find out category of centos. how? any specific specifications for that?
3. migration means need to create new with with new o.s(ubuntu etc) and copy files from centos7.right. is there any other need to do?
4. centos 7 coming to end life on june 30 means what? no more security patches or no more new updates or no more centos available?
   please explain

I almost checked most of documents and websites to find out ec2 belongs to which category. but all are confusing.